# Varying the string in an HTML label or text control

Tags: html, database, string, rotation, label

Looking for an elegant and quick way to vary/rotate (rotate as in change value, not change orientation) the contents of an html Label (or textbox).

For example, on our website we would like a caption to sometimes say "Our Database Products are Great", other times have it populate with "Helping Small Businesses since 2004" etc.  The chosen string can be randomly selected from a set list, but should vary every time the web page is reloaded (ok if the same one comes up more than once in a row).

What would be an easy way to accomplish this?  Is there a quick way to do it without Java?

Comment: Java is not Javascript.

Comment: You can do this on server side using server side includes or a server scripting language like PHP or ASP - then pages are served to the user with the content already in it. Or you can do this client side which involves using JavaScript to fill/replace the content of an element. It depends completely on what kind of setup you have.

Comment: In which language is written you website? Are you using simple static HTML pages? Or is a CMS built with server side technologies?

Answer (score 1):

Java is the easy way.

add a div and then update it with text every few seconds.

```
var text = ["My text 1", "My text 2", "My text 3"];
var value = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("div id");
setInterval(change, 1000);
function change() {
 elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
    value++;
    if(value >= text.length) { value = 0; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use JavaScript (if you can rely on your users having JavaScript). Add an `id` to the HTML element which will store the message, and add the following JavaScript code (replacing `randommessage` with you id) and adding any other messages to the `messages` array.

```
messages = ["Our Database Products are Great", "Helping Small Businesses since 2004", "Some other message"];

document.getElementById("randommessage").innerHTML = messages[Math.floor(Math.random()*messages.length)]
```

[Live JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/rra9zz51/)

Answer (score 1):

```
        <html>
            <head>
                <script>
                    function myFunction() {
                        var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
                        var randomCar = cars[Math.floor(Math.random() * cars.length)];
                        alert(randomCar);
                        document.getElementById('randomName').innerHTML = randomCar;
                    }
                </script>
            </head> 
            <body onload="myFunction()">
                <label id="randomName"></label>
            </body>
        </html>
```